# Setting png device in Rprofile

Tags: r

I am building a web application that has a limited R console. I would like to do something like

```
png(filename="pic.png")
```

for each session, so I can display the results on the web. When I tried to put the function into .Rprofile I get `"unknown function png"`.

I tried `library("graphics")` right in there - but that did not help. Is there a good way to run this code at startup without it being part of the session?

EDIT: Highlighted the code and error.

Comment: Actually png is in package `grDevices`, so you'd need `library(grDevices)`.... but do you know that you also need to close the png device (using `dev.off()`) to make the image file content available ?

Comment: The png device also need x11 for fonts.  For true headless mode, use one of he the cairo device(s) [there are packages] which can generate png files as well and do not require x11.